# Can you pass flags to the command that docker runs?

Tags: docker

The documentation for the `run` command follows the following syntax:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

however I've found at times that I want to pass a flag to `[COMMAND]`.

For example, I've been working with [this image](https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr), where the `[COMMAND]` as specified in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr/blob/master/5.2/Dockerfile) is:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/solr/bin/solr -f"]
```

Is there any way to tack on flags to `"/opt/solr/bin/solr -f"` so that it's in the form `"/opt/solr/bin/solr -f [-MY FLAGS]"`?

Do I need to edit the DockerFile or is there some built in functionality for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) directive of a *Dockerfile* is the command that would be run when the container starts *if* no command was specified in the `docker run` command.

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.

---

In your case, just use the `docker run` command as follow to override the default command specified in the *Dockerfile*:

```
docker run makuk66/docker-solr /bin/bash -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr -f [your flags]"
```

Answer (score 12):

There is a special directive [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) which fits your needs. Unlike `CMD` it will add additional flags at the end of your command.

For example, you can write

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

and run it with

```
docker run <image_name> -c "print(1)"
```

Note, that this only will work if you write command in `exec` form (via `["...", "..."]`), otherwise `ENTRYPOINT` will invoke `shell` and pass your args there, not to your script.

More generally, you can combine `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["ping"]  
CMD ["www.google.com"]
```

Where `CMD` means default args for your `ENTRYPOINT`. Now you can run both of

```
docker run <image_name>
docker run <image_name> yandex.ru
```

and only `CMD` will be replaced.

Full reference about how `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` interact can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)